# Confusion between Singleton and Static method Java

Tags: java, class, static, singleton

Suppose I want to implement the class which will provide me `Connection` for database connectivity. I can implement the same thing with two different code snaps given below.

***Method 1:***

```
class DBConnection1 {
    private static DBConnection1 instance = new DBConnection1();
    private DBConnection1(){

    }
    public static DBConnection1 getInstance(){
        return instance; 
    }
    public Connection getConnection(){
        Connection connection = null;
        //do my stuff to init the connection
        return connection;
    }
}
```

***Method 2:***

```
class DBConnection2 {
    public static Connection getConnection(){
        Connection connection = null;
        //do my stuff to init the connection
        return connection;
    }
}
```

And Accessing the above methods like,

```
class TestConnection{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //using method 1
        Connection connection1 =  DBConnection1.getInstance().getConnection();
        //using method 1
        Connection connection2 =  DBConnection2.getConnection();
    }
}
```

I have little doubt which is better and why? And what is difference over there?

Comment: What are the benefits of those two methods while returning a `null` connection?

Comment: You singleton looks well wrong. I would have expected Instance to return a Connection, and Connection to be only created if it had not been already.

Comment: I don't think these code blocks are doing what you think they are. You're creating a new connection each time, regardless of which one you call.

Answer (score 3):

At a very high level you might get confused and it looks that they both are doing the same task. But there is a lot of difference. I'm answering this question in general. You can understand the advantages based on your application(type).

Singleton stores common data in only one place. It will greatly simplify the architecture of a program and helps you to reuse code. Singletons allow you control object state much easier. This improves code-sharing, and quality of code. Hence it becomes easier to maintain. Singleton allows you to override in case you want to override it. Lazy loading can be done using Singleton Classes. Singleton is more object oriented. Static objects are stored in stack but singleton objects are stored in heap.

Static classes are difficult to test when compared to Singleton(Singleton is very easy to mock. Eg- while using JUnit Tests). If you are using Spring or any such dependency injection framework, its better to use Singleton than static. Static Class cannot be passed to a method or inherited. Static classes can create issues in a concurrent environment due to shared data. its better not to maintatin state inside static class. You can refer more about Singleton here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern or http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_singleton.htm .

The only advantage that i see with static class is that its faster. Use static only when a set of functions have to be kept together.

Comment: I think you made a lot of big claims here such as "It will greatly simplify the architecture of a program and helps you to reuse code.".  In fact many people view singletons as crippling architecture due to global access for a start.

Comment: Every thing depends on a use case. If it's not worth the pattern it would have been used. Here explanation adequately fits the question.

Comment: Everything has advantages and disadvantages. You can't just look at a single side of a coin.

Comment: I agree but you could replace 'singletons' with 'globals' and say the same thing.  Globals might be useful occasionally (maybe a logger) but they don't allow code reuse.

Comment: Yeah.but the question spoke about Singleton. And I specific to that. If we start taking different concepts,answers become huge. Its just your opinion. I don't deny it but you should respect others answers as well. Down vote neither helps you nor me.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you try to achieve. For example, if you are sure that you'll need this connection through all your app lifecycle - static method is for you. But if you are not sure about that - use singleton. But in real projects you should probably not use static methods for anything but some kind of utils methods, because singleton is much more flexible comparing to a static methods.

But there are minimum one more pattern that you'll probably be interested in. [Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). It could be a little bit more complex than a singleton, but again it's much more flexible. The main point of if that in a big project you may need some functionality providing by database and you'll use one class to access it. But later data separated by two databases and two classes with the same interface and instead if rewriting the code of classes that use a database, you changed implementation that would be injected in a particular class. There are much more benefits of using dependency injection that I described, but I hope you'll got the point.

Answer (score 1):

The two alternatives are equivalent. However, I would prefer the singleton one, because it is easier to swap the implementation or override behavior with subclassing in the future.

Another point that will make much more difference is whether to create a new connection for every use or reuse connection objects. This will make a lot of difference concerning prepared statements and commits / rollbacks.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to have a connection factory, better to to implement method1.
Because you could change you code inside of you Factory with few impact in the rest of the App.

Caution if reusing the connection, since you can share context, and that can be something you don't want!

Better is to live the `ConnectionFactory` get from connection's pool, one connection, then using it, then releasing it.... etc.

See factory pattern : if this is a connection factory that serves connections, better to see [Factory Method Pattern](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Factory_method_pattern)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up two different patterns, namely `Static Factory Method` (not the same as the GoF `Factory Method`) and `Singleton`.

Static Factory Method is concerned with creating instances. The Singleton pattern is used to ensure, that there is only one object of the Singleton class.

E.g. a typical static factory method:

```
public DBConnection {

    private DBConnection(String param) {
        //...
    }

    public static DBConnection createConnection(String param) {
        return new DBConnection(param);
    }

}
```

Note, that typically a factory method is called `create...` or `getNewInstance` or something similar to emphasize, that this method will always return a *new* instance.

The same as a Singleton:

```
public DBConnection {

    private static DBConnection instance;

    private DBConnection(String param) {
        //...
    }

    public static DBConnection getInstance() {
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new DBConnection("fixed param!");
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

Note how the same instance is always returned after it was created lazily.

Nevertheless those pattern can coexist - e.g. a singleton can use a static factory method to create the instance:

```
public DBConnection {

    private static DBConnection instance;

    private DBConnection(String param) {
        //...
    }

    public static DBConnection createInstance(String param) {
        return new DBConnection(param);
    }

    public static DBConnection getInstance() {
        if(instance == null){
            instance = DBConnection.createInstance("param");
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

I intentionally left the static factory method public, to emphasize the difference between `getInstance` and `createInstance` here.

Also `private` constructors play an important role in those patterns it enforces that the `createInstance` / `getInstance` methods *must* be used to get hold of an instance.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you should not use the `Singleton` approach. This is because you seem to be returning a new `connection` everytime the `getConnection` method is called. If this is what you really want, there is no point using a `Singleton` class. You should go with method 2 instead.

The long answer is that you seem to be confused about what a `Singleton` really is. The purpose of a `Singleton` class is to ensure that there is only one object of a given class created for a given `ClassLoader`, thus ensuring that the state of such an object is global. If your class does not contain any `state`, you might as well use a class that contains only `static` methods. Alternately, if you are using an `IoC` container such as `Spring` or `Guice`, you can have a `Singleton` enforced via the framework rather than explicitly design your class as a `Singleton`. A class that is explicitly designed to be a `Singleton` but does not have any state really doesn't make much sense.